# Performing a k-means clustering with raster time series

Tags: raster, r, time-series

I would like to perform a k-means clustering on time series data. I tried doing it with `rts` package.

```
library(rts)
path <- system.file("external", package="rts")
lst <- list.files(path=path,pattern='.asc$',full.names=TRUE)
raster <- stack(lst)

AOI = extent(c(649349,652733,5729977,5732891))
raster=crop(raster,AOI)

dates <- c("2000-02-01","2000-03-01","2000-04-01","2000-05-01")
dates <- as.Date(dates)
timeseries <- rts(raster,dates)
```

Since this package looks to be built on `raster` package I tried to retrieve the values like I would have done with `raster` : `values(timeseries)` but it doesn't work. I haven't found a way to browse my data in the [package documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rts/rts.pdf).

I also tried to store values in a list :

```
values = NULL
for (i in 1:ncell(timeseries[[1]]) ){
  values = c(values, timeseries[i])
}
```

But it stores values as numeric vectors, so I lose the time dimension (even though out of the loop, `timeseries[1]` gives an xts object).

Do you know a way to do it? Or have you already done a classification or clustering on raster time series with another package or method?

Comment: You can get the data out of a raster stack easy enough (`r[i,j]`) so you need to define the "distance" between two time series and then compute a distance matrix for each pixel pair. You can treat the data as a vector, you don't need to make them time series objects (unless you have a package that does time series kmeans) to feed into `stats::kmeans`?

Comment: I didn't believe you when you said there is no need to use the data as a time series object. So I found a package designed for time series clustering (`TSclust::pam`). It turns out it gives the same clusters `stats::kmeans` gives. You were right, a simple vector works as good as a time series.

Answer (score 1):

Using sample data from the `rts` package:

```
path <- system.file("external", package="rts") # location of files
lst <- list.files(path=path,pattern='.asc$',full.names=TRUE)
r <- stack(lst) # creating a RasterStack object
```

which has four layers, you can feed the `as.matrix` of that as a four-column matrix to `stats::kmeans`, and it will (by default) take the root-mean-square (pythagoras in 4d) distance for clustering. Then put the cluster member values into a new single layer raster:

```
km = kmeans(as.matrix(r), 3)
cl = raster(r)
cl[] = km$cluster
plot(cl)
```

[image]

Showing the cluster membership from 1 to 3. Pixels that are green (cluster 3) come from stacks of 4 pixels that are generally closer together in root-mean-square different than they are to pixels in the white (cluster 1) or yellow (cluster 2) areas according to the kmeans clustering process.

Bonus points: hierarchical clustering. You can use the same idea to feed `hclust`, but give it a distance matrix, and then cut the tree wherever (3 here to compare with hclust):

```
hc = hclust(dist(as.matrix(r)))
hcr = raster(r)
hcr[] = cutree(hc,3)
plot(hcr)
```

[image]

Similar but different. How different? You can do a cross-tabulation of cluster assignments for the two methods:

```
> table(hcr[], cl[])
   
      1   2   3
  1   0 107   0
  2 521  85  94
  3   0   0 483
```

Endless fun.